# unable to extract facebook video url using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, flask, beautifulsoup

I have a python route function which makes request to the website [www.fbdown.net](http://www.fbdown.net) with facebook    video link in parameter , in that website we get html page with actual downloadble url of the video.    I want to parse that HTML code and get the video download url.

1st Method tried with Beautifulsoup:-

But my route function getting the Wrong HTML page with title "Just a moment".. I also added some delay but same response.

```
@app.route('/downloadS', methods=['GET'])
def download_video_S():
# Get the video link from the POST request
video_link = request.args.get('link')

# Send a GET request to the download page
response = requests.get('https://fdown.net/download.php', params={'URLz': video_link})

time.sleep(30)

# Parse the HTML response with Beautiful Soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

print(soup)

# Find the SD and HD links
sd_link = soup.find('a', {'id': 'sdlink'})['href']
hd_link = soup.find('a', {'id': 'hdlink'})['href']

# Return the links as a JSON response
response = {'sd_link': sd_link, 'hd_link': hd_link}
return jsonify(response)`
```

2nd Method tried with Selenium, it is working but using chrome:
I want to just extract actual download url of the video, I tried using selenium its working but it's open chrome browser

Route function which using selenium

```
@app.route('/downloadFace', methods=['GET'])
def download_video_Face():
# Get the video link from the POST request
video_link = request.args.get('link')

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Set up the Chrome options
# chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # run Chrome in headless mode

# # Set up the driver with the Chrome options


# Load the page
driver.get("https://fdown.net/")

# Find the input field and enter the video link
input_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "URLz")
input_field.send_keys(video_link)

# Find the download button and click it
download_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit']")
download_button.click()

# Wait for the download links to appear
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

# Get the SD and HD links
sd_link = driver.find_element(By.ID, "sdlink").get_attribute("href")
hd_link = driver.find_element(By.ID, "hdlink").get_attribute("href")

# Close the driver
driver.quit()

# Return the links as a JSON response
response = {'sd_link': sd_link, 'hd_link': hd_link}
return jsonify(response)`
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to perform a POST request, passing the URL through the `data` parameter. Additionally, change the user agent header.

```py
response = requests.post('https://fdown.net/download.php', data={'URLz': video_link}, headers={'User-Agent': 'Some User Agent'})
```